# Solving Laplace equation in the center of a square

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, harmonic-functions

I have been asked to solve the following problem:

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{c} \Delta u =0 \;\;\; (x,y)\in(0,1)\times(0,1) \\ u(0,y)=1 \;,\; u(1,y)=0 \;,\; u(x,0)=0 \;,\; u(x,1)=0 \;,\; x,y\in(0,1) \end{array} \right. $$

They ask me to compute the value $u(1/2,1/2)$

When solving the equation, I get a series from I don't know to compute the convergence on the value that they ask me to solve the equation.

I have seen on other questions on the forum that this value can be obtained without solving the equation (using the rotational invariance of Laplace equation), by as the mean of the values of the function in the boundaries. So that in this case this would be $\frac{0+0+0+1}{4}=1/4$.

However I am not able to reach this point. I would be grateful if anybody could help

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you link the questions you cite ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2246236/evaluating-solution-to-laplaces-equation-at-centre-of-square   In this solution I can't see how values of $T$, $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ at the center of the square are related

Comment: T, T1, T2 and T3 seem to be the same solution rotated around the centre of the square by 90 degrees. Therefore since the centre is a fixed point all four solutions should share there the same value

Comment: It makes sense that the solution is the same, but what I dont know is how do they know that the solution in the center is exactly $H/4$ being H the value in one border of the square (in my case 1)

Comment: If you sum the four solutions you find the solution to the Laplace function with constant value of the border, which itself is the constant function everywhere

Comment: So the four solutions (1) share the same value in the centre (2) sum to 1 everywhere (in particular in the centre). From this you recover the value in the centre. It looks a nice trick.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not realising that when the values in the border are constants the solution has to be a constant because of the maximum principle. Now I get it. Thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem. Actually if you know that the function is constant on the border at a value K you can just check that f(x)=K is a solution (I.e. harmonic and with the right value on the boarder). Since the solution is unique than it is the solution. Not sure you need the maximum principle but I may be missing smth ?

Comment: Probably the maximum principle is exactly what needed to show that the solution is unique. But if you already know this uniqueness property than you can just it for your purposes without having to pass again from the maximum principle. In any case you are already using the uniqueness property when linking the various Ts together.